# Unable to install @vue/cli in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ubuntu, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install the Vue CLI in ubuntu (WSL), but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. I ran the command `yarn add global @vue/cli`, and I also tried with `npm install @vue/cli --global`. The commands run as though they were successfull, but as soon as I run `vue --version`, it throws `command vue not found`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your global node_modules is missing from your `PATH`. Run `npm -g root` to find where your global node_modules is installed, add it to your `PATH`, then restart the shell to ensure the `PATH` is loaded for the next command.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I added the dir to the PATH by adding ```export PATH="$PATH:/dr/to/node_modules"``` in my .bashrc file but it is still the same. Thank you for your time, though.

Comment: It should point to the `.bin` under `node_modules` (where the `vue` symlink lives)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! For some reason, it did not work, but I tried the npm install instead, and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! (partly) after a lot of time, I went with the npm installation and it worked out of the box. To use yarn, add the following to your ~/.bashrc:

`export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)"`